# Disabling all devices in /proc/acpi/wakeup permanently

Tags: acpi, sysctl

In an effort to weed out an acpi problem, I need to set all the `/proc/acpi/wakeup` device variables to disabled.

For the time being I'm doing it with `acpitool` and a script in /etc/rc.local ...

```
usr/bin/acpitool -W 1 && usr/bin/acpitool -W 2 && usr/bin/acpitool -W 3 && usr/bin/acpitool -W 5 && usr/bin/acpitool -W 6 && usr/bin/acpitool -W 7 && usr/bin/acpitool -W 8 && usr/bin/acpitool -W 9
```

... which works but is really ugly and rough. =-/

Unfortunately the `acpitool` manfile has no indication on how to set multiple devices at the same time and it may not even be an option. Really don't know.

I've looked at the possibility of changing the settings in sysctl as explained in [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-set-sysctl-variables/) post, but `sysctl -a` does not show me any variable related to the devices I need to set to disabled ie: USBx and EUSB, or any of the other devices listed in `/proc/acpi/wakeup` for that matter.

How could I get this done in a more efficient manner?

This is all under Devuan ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop. For example:

```
for i in $(seq 1 9)
do
    /usr/bin/acpitool -W $i
done
```

The `seq 1 9` is actually a separate command that generates a series of numbers `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`. The `$( ... )` construct runs the enclosed command and uses its standard output as part of the command line. If you want/need to, you can just specify the numbers individually, making the first line of the loop be e.g. `for i in 1 5 7 9`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll check this out and see how it works. I take it that the seq is not a range (1-9) but separate digits (1 5 7 9 ).

Comment: The `seq 1 9` is actually a separate command that generates a series of numbers `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`. The `$( ... )` construct runs the enclosed command and uses its standard output as part of the command line. If you want/need to, you can just specify the numbers individually, making the first line of the loop be e.g. `for i in 1 5 7 9`.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Now, if I understand correctly, using `acpitool` would be the equivalent of command line `echo $usbx > /proc/acpi/wakeup` but with an application. I have been wondering just where

Comment: ... the seetings reflected in `/proc/acpi/wakeup` come from.Thought I'd have to specify _just_ the device numbers to be disabled but it worked, either acting _only_ on the enabled ones or setting them _all_ to disabled (not the same thing I think) but the result is the intended one. Thank you for taking the time to explain it, now I have to study some bash.